# How to create a list in react using redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am trying to make a list using redux. As react works on component. So I want to make list as a separate component.

When a User fills in an input field and presses the `add` button it should add a list item. But currently it is not showing a list item.

Here is my code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/eCZSo6Rl5odN1hTb6BCW?p=preview

I am currently doing it like this:

```
  <r names ={this.props.names}/>


const r = (props) => {
    alert('---')
    return (
        <li>
            <span>hiii</span>
        </li>
    );
};
```

When `this.props.names` changes it should fire the render function. But it is not calling the render function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your components should be capital. `r` should be `R` through out.

Updated plnkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/ENpx2s7JdW0AZUYtzKOj?p=preview

This is because React treats lower case elements as browser native elements (div, p, span, etc) and capital elements as app level elements.

Answer (score 1):

React Component must begin with `UpperCase` letters. Change that and it will solve your problem

```
render() {
    const data =[{"name":"test1"},{"name":"test2"}];
    var listItems = this.props.names.map(function(d, idx){
      return (<R key={idx}></R>)
    })
    return (
      <div>
      <input type="text" onChange ={this.changeEv}/>
      <button onClick={this.addName}>add</button>
      {listItems}
      </div>
    );
  }
} 
const R = (props) => {
    alert('---')
    return (
        <li>
            <span>hiii</span>
        </li>
    );
};
```

**[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/LyEA0Kz608iWqWVkeTjC?p=preview)**